# Why is Busybox still not recognized after installed properly?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adb, windows, shell, busybox

Busybox is installed in `/system/bin` successfully already, but I still can't call it as instructed in [Using cut or sed in Android busybox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106725/3416774):

```
C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\adb>adb shell whence sed
/system/bin/sed

C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\adb>adb shell whence busybox
/system/bin/busybox

C:\Users\Acer\Downloads\adb>busybox
'busybox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake here is that you're trying to run Busybox by issuing `busybox` in your **Windows terminal**. This way, Windows searches for a program called **busybox** in its `PATH`, but doesn't find it, since it resides inside the **/system/bin** directory of your **Android device**.

To run any command residing on your Android device, you need to preface the actual command with `adb shell`, so `adb shell busybox`, in your case.

Comment: Do you know why we need Busybox at all? Android is Linux, why can't I use `grep`?

Comment: @Ooker Android is not Linux, even if it inherits a great deal of characteristics. Toolbox, Busybox and later Toybox were used as lightweight binaries, compared to the size of the standard binaries.

Comment: I see. As what I see about [Toybox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toybox), it is included in Marshmallow, and has `grep`. Why do Busybox still be needed to install?

Comment: @Ooker The story behind Toybox, is that it was started as a toolset with a less strict license than the GPL. Still, compared to Busybox, Toybox is quite young and thus missing a part of the features of its brother (look [here](http://www.landley.net/toybox/todo.txt) for a to-do list by its main developer).

Comment: I'm surprised that some basic Linux commands (`grep`, `sed`) are not included in Toybox. Off-topic I know, but if Google sees it's useful, why don't they make it equivalent to Busybox?

Comment: @Ooker Google is not the developer of Toybox. They just included it from Marshmallow onwards. Besides, *<rant>Google is too much focused on their Play Services and data mining to care about Android</rant>*. I should also mention that comments are not for chatting, and redirect you to [Toybox's site](http://landley.net/toybox/about.html) for more info.