# Busybox is not detected even when it has been installed

Tags: magisk, busybox

The [Debloater module](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-terminal-debloater-v17-3-2-debloat-systemlessly.3584163/) module of Magisk tells me that Busybox isn't detected:

```
root@android:/data/adb # debloat
debloat
! Busybox not detected
Please install one (@osm0sis' busybox recommended)

=========================================
Debloater (Terminal Emulator) v17.3.3(76)
by veez21
=========================================
BusyBox not found!

=========================================
```

However I've installed it via Magisk Manager, and I have rebooted after installation.

[image: Screenshot indicating Busybox is installed]

Why is that? Is it a problem?

<sub>There is a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/171751/94084), but it's because the OP confuses Windows command and Android shell command.</sub>

Comment: Try uninstalling both, first install busybox of Osmosis, reboot, install debloater and reboot

Comment: The module is abandoned by developer. No more [development](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-terminal-debloater-v17-3-2-debloat-systemlessly.3584163/post-83889969), so if you want that badly try with earlier versions of Magisk